# Problemas al intentar conseguir datos de una fila dinámica en una tabla HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo creada una tabla en HTML sencilla a la cual le inserto datos dinamicamente mediante JavaScript, de los cuales necesito tomar 1 al darte clic en un botón el cual se llama seleccionar para posteriormente llenar otra tabla en HTML de manera dinámica.

El problema es que no me permite tomar el texto de las filas, al parecer los marca como nulos.

Anexo el HTML y el JavaScript

```
<div id="tblSeleccionarPx" class="row" hidden="true">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th scope="col" hidden="true">Id</th>
           <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
           <th scope="col">Tel&eacute;fono</th>
           <th scope="col" class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="tbodySeleccionarPx">
         </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT DONDE LLENO LA TABLA ANTERIOR.

```
function BuscarPaciente(){
 $('#btnBuscarPaciente').attr("disabled",true);
 var nombre = $('#nombrePacienteConsulta').val();

 var band = false;

 if(nombre.length == 0){
  alert("Favor de ingresar nombre del paciente");
  band = false;
  }else{
   band = true;
  }

  if(band == true){
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: baseurl + 'Manager/BuscarPaciente/',
   data:  {
    nombre: nombre,
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){

    $("#tblSeleccionarPx").removeAttr("hidden");
    $("#btnBuscarPaciente").removeAttr("disabled");

    var len = response.length;
    var datosJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

    if(len > 0){
      // Read values
      for (var i = 0; i < datosJson.length; i++) {
        elements = '<tr>'+
            '<td class="pacid" hidden="true">'+datosJson[i].id_paciente+'</td>'+
            '<td class="pacnom">'+datosJson[i].nombre_paciente+'</td>'+
            '<td class="telefonopx">'+datosJson[i].telefono_paciente+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+
              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="SeleccionarPaciente()">'+
                  '<strong>SELECCIONAR</strong> <span class="fas fa-check"></span>'+
              '</button>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
        $(elements).appendTo('#tbodySeleccionarPx');
      } 
    }else{
      alert("¡Ha ocurrido algo al buscar el registro, intente nuevamente!");
    }

   }
});
}else{
 $("#btnBuscarPaciente").removeAttr("disabled");
 }
}
```

CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT DONDE INTENTO TOMAR LOS VALORES INSERTADOS PARA POSTERIORMENTE LLENAR OTRA TABLA.

```
function SeleccionarPaciente(){
 var nuevo = document.getElementsByClassName("pacnom");
 var row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
 var textid = row.find(".pacid").text(); // Find the text
 var textname = row.find(".pacnom").text(); // Find the text
 var id = textid.trim();
 var name = textname.trim();
 $("#tblConfirmarPx").removeAttr("hidden");
 elements = '<tr>'+
            '<td class="pxid" hidden="true">'+id+'</td>'+
            '<td class="pxnombre">'+'name: '+name+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" class="pxpa form-control"/></td>'+
            '<td>'+
              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block confirmarpx">'+
                  '<strong>CONFIRMAR</strong> <span class="fas fa-check-double"></span>'+
              '</button>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
$(elements).appendTo('#tbodyConfirmarPx');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue que para cuando se crea contenido dinamico es necesario buscar de manera global el botón, es decir, mandar llamar el document y dentro de el buscar el botón.

Dejo el código aquí abajo.

```
$(document).on('click', '.seleccionarpx', function(){
 var row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
 var textid = row.find(".pacid").text(); // Find the text
 var textname = row.find(".pacnom").text(); // Find the text
 var id = textid.trim();
 var name = textname.trim();
 $("#tblConfirmarPx").removeAttr("hidden");
 elements = '<tr>'+
            '<td class="pxid" hidden="true">'+id+'</td>'+
            '<td class="pxnombre">'+name+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" class="pxpa form-control"/></td>'+
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block confirmarpx">'+
              '<strong>CONFIRMAR</strong> <span class="fas fa-check-double"></span></button></td>'+
        '</tr>';
 $(elements).appendTo('#tbodyConfirmarPx');
});
```

Como se puede notar el cambio mas importante esta en la primera linea, que es la manera en la que se busca el botón.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto, utilice parte de tu código y emule los resultados y solo me enfoque en el problema de capturar los valores:

```js
$(".seleccionar").click((e) => {

  const fila = $(e.target).parents("tr");
  const id = fila.find("td:eq(0)").text();
  const nombre = fila.find("td:eq(1)").text();
  const telefono = fila.find("td:eq(2)").text();
  
  console.log("id = "+id);
  console.log("nombre = "+nombre);
  console.log("telefono = "+telefono);

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th scope="col" hidden="true">Id</th>
           <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
           <th scope="col">Tel&eacute;fono</th>
           <th scope="col" class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="tbodySeleccionarPx">
          <tr>
            <td class="pacid" hidden="true">1</td>
            <td class="pacnom">Daniel</td>
            <td class="telefonopx">+5812345678</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block seleccionar">
                  <strong>SELECCIONAR</strong> <span class="fas fa-check"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="pacid" hidden="true">2</td>
            <td class="pacnom">David</td>
            <td class="telefonopx">+5899999999</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block seleccionar">
                  <strong>SELECCIONAR</strong> <span class="fas fa-check"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: **David Leonardo Molina Ruiz Dav**, no entiendo porque no puedo responderte en tu propia respuesta. Te agradezco el tiempo que te haz tomado en formular esa respuesta, pero no me dio resultado, creo que el problema esta en el que los `<td></td>` y los botones se crean de manera **dinámica**, aunque sigo sin entender el porque falla.